# Tabular format data in node js email

Tags: node.js

in my node js project, I am using gmail to send mail, mails are going fine, except that when I put data in tabular form with HTML code then rather printing the data in tabular form, it simply prints the html code.

what am I missing here, should I user any specific npm, as of now I am using nodemailer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might be writing the HTML code in the text field. Use nodemailer's html field

```
var mailOptions = {
    html: '<b>Hello world!</b>',

}
```

and write your HTML code into this field.